JWT token location in Blazor WASM
I've just started my first Blazor WASM project which requires authentication. We use Auth0 for user identity management.
Following this article on Auth0 website, I was able to get authentication working: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-blazor-webassembly-apps/
My question is about where the actual access and refresh tokens are stored. Typically, they're stored in local or session storage in the browser but when I checked both, I didn't see the actual tokens. I can see that some settings such as my client Id, etc are stored in session storage but I don't see the actual tokens -- see image.

Where does Blazor (WASM) store JWT tokens? Or is there a way to access and inspect them through a method?

I'm not sure about Blazor. But in general, there is no need to store the tokens, they can be kept in memory. From security perspective it's bad to use / store a refresh token.

The best approach to store a token is to use an HTTP-only cookie. It's not available for JS and handled automatically by the browser. But if you use Auth0, you shouldn't worry about that as Auth0 does it. You should just implement SSO in your app and not handle passwords or tokens, leave it to an Identity Provider.

This screenshot isn't a successful login. There should be a key named "oidc.user:https://xxxxxx" which store all the tokens. Below is my screenshot after login:

You could try following sample:

In Auth0 dashboard, create a "SPA" application. do following settings.




Create "Blazor WebAssembly Standalone" template. (I use .net8) Install package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.

Create "appsettings.json" in "wwwroot" folder with content:


{
  "Auth0": {
    "Authority": "https://dev-unrb5hhiwnqovxba.us.auth0.com",
    "ClientId": "65DBttLLDUfN0GA3NwIC38J5xufv36Oe",
    "DefaultScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "offline_access"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:7028/authentication/logout-callback",
    "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:7028/authentication/login-callback",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
}


Create RedirectToLogin.razor

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateToLogin("authentication/login");
    }
}


Create Authentication.razor

@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />
@code{
    [Parameter] public string? Action { get; set; }
}


In program.cs add

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Auth0", options.ProviderOptions);
});


Modify App.razor

     <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p role="alert">You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>


Home.razor (login and logout)

@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Hello, @context.User.Identity?.Name!
        <button @onclick="BeginLogOut">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <button @onclick="BeginLogIn">Log In</button>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code{
    public void BeginLogIn()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("authentication/login");
    }
    public void BeginLogOut()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateToLogout("authentication/logout");
    }
}


Counter.razor (Use IAccessTokenProvider to get AccessToken)

@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject IAccessTokenProvider _tokenProvider

@attribute [Authorize]

<button @onclick="ShowAccessToken">Show Access Token</button>
<p/>
access token :@accessToken

@code {
    private string accessToken { get; set; } = "";

    private async Task ShowAccessToken()
    {
        var result=await _tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();                     
    }  
}

Just note that there's a built-in IAccessTokenProvider to get access token directly. But unfortunately, I didn't see a similar "refreshtokenprovider" method. But as we know that the refresh token is in the browser session storage, it is not hard to get it using Blazored.SessionStorage.
Reference : 
https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/refresh-tokens/get-refresh-tokens
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#redirecttologin-component 

Thank you. For some reason, the UI was showing that I was logged in but the token wasn't in SessionStorage. I created a new app following the article and sure enough, it worked and the token is there. However, when I manually delete the access token from SessionStorage, the UI still shows that I'm logged in. So, the authentication state is clearly stored somewhere and it's not checking to see if the access token is still available or not. In other words, things are going out of sync and Blazor is not checking it. Is this normal? Looks like a bug to me.

@Sam Not a bug. If you don't delete the cookies. The application will request new token from Auth0 and generate the session again.
